# How to change DIV content in a different page?

Tags: ajax, html, replace

I know there is ways to change DIV content within a single page. Using Ajax for example to dynamically get div content from an external .html file and then replace Div content using load or get functions.

However, is there a way to do this on a different page?

For example, say there is 2 pages. One.html, and Two.html.
I want a button on the first page (One.html), that when clicked, will change DIV content (by default the div box is empty, I want the button to insert text into the box basically) for a specific DIV Id on page 2 (Two.html).

So the process is basically: Click button on One.html, some function gets div content from external html (Three.html for example), and the uses that content to update an empty div on Two.html. Also, I would like to load some basic CSS in a similar fashion. Not only insert text into the box, but also change the background color and text color.

Thank You!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do but JQuery  .load() functions allows you to load content from another html page into your DIVs http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just store the info and send it to the next page, say, with the HTTP request and submit methods get and post.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp